# another Wordpress contact form 7 file upload issue

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I know this problem is often related, but i'm struggling with the informations i get. I want to make an upload file field which handle files up to 10mo.

here is a sample of my phpinfo :

```
max_input_time : 300
max_execution_time : 300
upload_max_filesize : 300000M
post_max_size : 300000M
memory_limit : 512M
```

I also added this line to wp-config.php

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');
```

to finish, here's the notation of my file input in contact form 7 :

```
[file file limit:20mb filetypes:txt|pdf|doc|docx|odt class:fileinput]
```

with these settings, i can upload files up to 8mo, but i need 10mo. Can't see what's wrong at this point

Comment: Have you looked into possible limitation of e-mail attachment size?

Comment: Check your php max_upload_size limit for your site, Create a php file and enter the `phpinfo()` function it and place the file in root of your site, then run it `YouSiteDomain/phpFileName.php`, search for `max_upload_size`.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the size limit in bytes - the output for 20mb in bytes is `20971520`

```
[file file limit:20971520 filetypes:txt|pdf|doc|docx|odt class:fileinput]
```

Answer (score 1):

To allow files bigger than 1Mb(?), I had to edit

```
wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/modules/file.php
```

and changes 1048576 to 10048576

```
$allowed_size = 10048576;
```

This will allow ContactForm7 to accept files until 10Mb files, if we have the server configured to it.

Comment: And will totally break the moment you update the plugin

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick fix if someone is still facing the same issue.

`contact-form-7/includes/form-tag.php`

- Find the public function:

  ```
  get_limit_option( $default_value = MB_IN_BYTES ) {
  ```
- Replace with:

  ```
  public function get_limit_option( $default_value = MB_IN_BYTES ) {return 99048576;
  ```
- Leave the other function code, as it just starts in return with the limit set to 99mb, as the above code.